# the right way use bit field print number in binary

Tags: c, bit-fields

here is the code I found using bit field print int number in binary, but I also read that bit field only using `unsigned`, `int` for its type, so, is it legal for this code using `char` type ?

```
struct bits
{
    unsigned char ch1 : 1;//01
    unsigned char ch2 : 1;
    unsigned char ch3 : 1;
    unsigned char ch4 : 1;
    unsigned char ch5 : 1;
    unsigned char ch6 : 1;
    unsigned char ch7 : 1;
    unsigned char ch8 : 1;
};

void main()
{
    int data = -1;
    int length = 4;

    struct bits *p = &data;

    while (length--)
    {
        printf("%d%d%d%d %d%d%d%d ",
            (p + length)->ch8,
            (p + length)->ch7,
            (p + length)->ch6,
            (p + length)->ch5,
            (p + length)->ch4,
            (p + length)->ch3,
            (p + length)->ch2,
            (p + length)->ch1
            );
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type.

Using `unsigned char` is allowable with some compilers as an "implementation-defined type".

`(p + length)->ch8` will go through the usual *integer promotions* being a parameters to a variadic function.  Thus `ch8` will be promoted to an `int`, which matches `"%d"`.

Code could use `unsigned`

```
struct bits {
    unsigned ch1 : 1;//01
    unsigned ch2 : 1;
    unsigned ch3 : 1;
    unsigned ch4 : 1;
    unsigned ch5 : 1;
    unsigned ch6 : 1;
    unsigned ch7 : 1;
    unsigned ch8 : 1;
};
```

Comment: thanks your answer, but by removing `char` with only `unsigned` left I got the wrong output 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 on my Xcode

Comment: @v2pro Although that output may not have been as desired, it is not "wrong".  Instead of using code like `struct bits *p = &data;`, use a `union` of 4 `struct bits` overlaying an `uint32_t`.  Your approach, as it stands, involves  undefined behavior.

Comment: There really are 3 questions here:  1) Can `unsigned char` allowable a bit-field? 2) Is `printf("%d...` The correct format? 3) Is `struct bits *p = &data;` OK.  This post answers  the first 2.  The last is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

GCC is [allowing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html) any integer type as a bitfield, as opposed to the C99 and C11 standards:

> *Allowable bit-field types other than _Bool, signed int, and unsigned
>   int (C99 and C11 6.7.2.1).* 
>   Other integer types, such as long int, and
>   enumerated types are permitted even in strictly conforming mode.